# sum of divisors of all divisors of a number

Tags: c++, algorithm, discrete-mathematics, number-theory

The very well explanation of below approach is [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-sum-divisors-divisors-natural-number/) .I was not able to write here due to formatting issues.

// C++ program to find sum of divisors of all 
     the divisors of a natural number.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

// Returns sum of divisors of all the divisors 
// of n 
int sumDivisorsOfDivisors(int n) 
{ 
    // Calculating powers of prime factors and 
    // storing them in a map mp[]. 
    map<int, int> mp; 
    for (int j=2; j<=sqrt(n); j++) 
    { 
        int count = 0; 
        while (n%j == 0) 
        { 
            n /= j; 
            count++; 
        } 

        if (count) 
            mp[j] = count; 
    } 

    // If n is a prime number 
    if (n != 1) 
        mp[n] = 1; 

    // For each prime factor, calculating (p^(a+1)-1)/(p-1) 
    // and adding it to answer. 
    int ans = 1; 
    for (auto it : mp) 
    { 
        int pw = 1; 
        int sum = 0; 

        for (int i=it.second+1; i>=1; i--) 
        { 
            sum += (i*pw); 
            pw *= it.first; 
        } 
        ans *= sum; 
    } 

    return ans; 
} 

// Driven Program 
int main() 
{ 
    int n = 10; 
    cout << sumDivisorsOfDivisors(n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I am not getting what is happening in this loop instead of adding to ans they are multiplying sum ,how they are calculating `(p^(a+1)-1)/(p-1)` and this to ans.can anyone help me with the intuition behind this loop.

I got this from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-sum-divisors-divisors-natural-number/)

```
for (auto it : mp) 
{ 
    int pw = 1; 
    int sum = 0; 

    for (int i=it.second+1; i>=1; i--) 
    { 
        sum += (i*pw); 
        pw *= it.first; 
    } 
    ans *= sum; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging so far?

Comment: The first loop is obtaining the prime divisors, and the number of times they are a factor.  (e.g.  if divisible by 8, the factor is 2 and the count is 3).  Incidentally, the code is not computing the sum of all divisors - it is computing the sum of the highest powers possible of the prime divisors  (e.g. if the value is divisible by 8, the sum will include the 8 but not 4 or 2).   That potentially leaves out several divisors from the sum.

Comment: I think you're confused by the *and **adding** it to answer.* The number of divisors due to another prime divisor depends on all other divisors, hence this is a multiplicative operation.

Comment: 'Divisors of divisors' is very strange terminology. Do you mean 'prime  factors'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider this statement:

(p<sub>1</sub><sup>0</sup>
 + p<sub>1</sub><sup>1</sup>
 +…+ 
p<sub>1</sub><sup>k<sub>1</sub></sup>) * (p<sub>2</sub><sup>0</sup> + p<sub>2</sub><sup>1</sup> +…+ p<sub>2</sub><sup>k<sub>2</sub></sup>)

Now, the divisors of any p<sup>a</sup>, for p as prime, are p<sup>0</sup>, p<sup>1</sup>,……, p<sup>a</sup>, and sum of diviors will be :

((p<sub>1</sub><sup>0</sup>) + (p<sub>1</sub><sup>0</sup> + p<sub>1</sub><sup>1</sup>) + .... + (p<sub>1</sub><sup>0</sup> + p<sub>1</sub><sup>1</sup> + ...+ p<sub>k</sub><sup>1</sup>)) * ((p<sub>2</sub><sup>0</sup>) + (p<sub>2</sub><sup>0</sup> + p<sub>2</sub><sup>1</sup>) + (p<sub>2</sub><sup>0</sup> + p<sub>2</sub><sup>1</sup> + p<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) + ... (p<sub>2</sub><sup>0</sup> + p<sub>2</sub><sup>1</sup> + p<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + .. + p<sub>2</sub><sup>k<sub>2</sub></sup>))

you can consider the above statement equivalent to bellow statement:

[[p<sub>1</sub><sup>0</sup> * (k<sub>1</sub> + 1) + p<sub>1</sub><sup>1</sup> * k<sub>1</sub> + p<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> * (k<sub>1</sub> - 1 ) + .... + (p<sub>1</sub><sup>k<sub>1</sub></sup>  * 1) ]] * [[p<sub>2</sub><sup>0</sup> * (k<sub>2</sub> + 1) + p<sub>2</sub><sup>1</sup> * (k<sub>2</sub>) + p<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> * (k<sub>2</sub> - 1 ) + .... + (p<sub>2</sub><sup>k<sub>2</sub></sup> * 1) ]]
in the code that you write in the post, the last statement was implemented.

for example if you consider n = 54 = 3<sup>3</sup> * 2<sup>1</sup>,
the ans is calculated in this format:

ans = (2<sup>0</sup> * 2 + 2<sup>1</sup> * 1) * (3<sup>0</sup> * 4 + 3<sup>1</sup> * 3 + 3<sup>2</sup> * 2 + 3<sup>3</sup> *1) =  4 * 58 = 232